# Redirect Output to stderr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, stderr

I want to redirect my output to stderr. I have a cron job

```
function auth_tester {
  cd /data/$1/current && bundle exec rake 'authentication:tester' 1>    /dev/null
}
```

which calls a rake task

```
namespace :authentication do

  desc "Automatically runs authentication tester and notifies in case of failure"
  task :tester => :environment do
    auth_tester_results = AuthenticationTester.perform

    exit(auth_tester_results.success? ? 0 : 1)
  end
end
```

If the 'auth_tester_results' boolean is a false I want **to redirect the output to stderr**. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already dealing with shell, do it in shell:

```
function auth_tester {
  cd /data/$1/current && \
  bundle exec rake 'authentication:tester' >/dev/null 2>&1
  #                                 HERE:  ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑
}
```

`stderr` has an `id = 2`, and we are redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null`, and `stderr` to `stdout`, eventually redirecting it to `/dev/null`.

To redirect `stdout` to `stderr`, use the opposite:

```
1>&2
```

To redirect the output from ruby, one uses proper receiver with [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts):

```
$stderr.puts "Goes to stderr"
```

Comment: My question is how will redirect my failure output to stderr. Your answer is also helpful on how to redirect stderr to stdout. But please answer on how will redirect my failure output to stderr

Answer (score 0):

Sending output to `STDERR` can be done via `print` or `puts`. Here I opt to send to [`STDERR`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants) rather than [`$stderr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+variables), but this will work for either:

```
STDERR.puts 'my message here'
```

If you'd like to change the exit status of your Ruby script (to show the script did not finish successfully, for example) you can use [`exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) with a parameter of `false`:

```
exit(false)
```

To both send output to STDERR *and* return an unsuccessful exit status, you can use [`abort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-abort):

```
abort 'my message here'
```

For additional information, ref [this article](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/how-to-exit-a-ruby-program/) from honeybadger.io.